# How to set TextField to empty string?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the text field to contain the data, and if `column` is null, the textField will be empty as well. This solution works, but it seems ugly as it contains a string. If I use an empty string '' then the label "becomes" the value ( instead of appearing as the label of the textfield, it appears as the value it self, position wise).. What do I need to change ?

```
  <TextField
          margin="normal"
          fullWidth
          inputProps={{
            disabled: true
          }}
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          label={labels.accountNumber}
          value={props.column || ' '}
    />
```

Comment: what does this mean then the label "becomes" the value?

Comment: I mean instead of appearing as the label of the textfield, it appears as the value it self.. I don't know why this is happening @Think-Twice

Comment: what is labels.accountNumber?

Comment: just a simple string ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add it will retain the label on upper side.

```
InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to display the account number label when props.column is null, you can use the following:

```
<TextField
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      inputProps={{
        disabled: true
      }}
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      label={labels.accountNumber}
      value={props.column !== null ? props.column : labels.accountNumber}
/>
```

Bare in mind that this still keeps the label property on the TextField.